# Shared mapreduce results collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, analytics

I have several Mongoid models that I'm running mapreduce on, and I'd like to store the unified results in a single `daily_stats` collection. My map & reduce functions work fine for all 3 models, but even when outputting via `collection.mapreduce(map, reduce, {:out => "daily_stats", :raw => true})`, the results of subsequent map reduce operations overwrite previous results, even it they don't have overlapping keys:

```
{'_id': "2012-06-01", 'values': {photos: 10}}
{'_id': "2012-06-02", 'values': {photos: 10}}
```

Values for `photos` get thrown out when a subsequent pass returns:

```
{'_id': "2012-06-01", 'values': {comments: 1}}
{'_id': "2012-06-02", 'values': {comments: 6}}
```

I tried merging also with `collection.mapreduce(map, reduce, {:out => {:merge => "daily_stats"}, :raw => true})`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The map & reduce functions are like this for each model:

Map:

```
function() {
    day = Date.UTC(this.created_at.getFullYear(), this.created_at.getMonth(), this.created_at.getDate());
    emit(day, {users: 1});
  };
```

Reduce:
function(key, values) {
        var users_added_count = 0;

```
    values.forEach(function(v) {
      users_added_count += parseInt(v['users']) || 0;
    });

    return {users: users_added_count};
  }
```

Here's some extra info about the resulting schema:

```
{ "_id" : 1337040000000,
 "value" : {
  "apartments" : 280,
  "price" : 1003653,
  "photos" : 83,
  "comments" : 0 } 
 }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't and/or can't run map reduce once and emit a single document, i.e.: emit(day, {users: 1}, {photos: 1}, {comments: 1})?

Comment: Oh, I see. You have initially have three separate collections- one for users, photos, and comments?  I'll write up an example to illustrate a way to merge the data.

Comment: Or is the document from the "resulting schema" your input data model? Sorry, to clarify, can you provide more examples of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the MongoDB documentation for map reduce (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions), you'll see that by default, the MR output collection replaces any existing collections with same name. "Merge" adds new data into the old output collection, but overwrites documents with the same key.

It looks like your key is the date? If

```
{'_id': "2012-06-01", 'values': {photos: 10}}
```

and

```
{'_id': "2012-06-01", 'values': {comments: 1}}
```

have the same key, the second document will replace the first when you run MR.  You either need to specify a more unique key, or you need to have multiple output collections (perhaps one for photos and one for comments?).

Comment: Correct, the key is the date. There's no way to merge items with the same key? Kind of like `$addToSet` does for array fields?

Comment: Since each document must have a unique _id field (in order to create a unique index on the document and keep track of the document's location), it is not possible to merge documents with the same key; however, I think there's a solution to your problem involving the finalize function in map reduce.  If you provide additional information about your MR functions and data schema, I may be able to help.

Comment: Sure, I added my map & reduce for users. THe other models are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit with a hash key to make it unique over your models

```
emit({day: day, type: '<model class name>'}, 1);
```